# Is there a reason not to always use leaky_relu

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

It seems to me that Relu activation is often extremely effective. And leaky relu solves its main drawback (the dying units).

So with the exception of output layers that require tanh, soft max, or sigmoid. Is there ever a reason that I wouldn't want to use leaky relu? (I'm aware that relu is computationally quicker than leaky relu, but a better model is worth spending a bit more time on)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For most application leaky_relu is good enough, but there are valid alternatives. Keep in mind that even leaky_relu has its own drawbacks, like having a new parameter alpha to tune.

[This article](https://mlfromscratch.com/activation-functions-explained/#/) explains various alternatives to the standard ReLU, and gives pros and cons for each one: